# Get Region from Lattitude/Longitude Coordinates via Python

Tags: python

I have been using countryinfo which can show you the 'subregion' of a country, i.e. a region within the continent (a sub collection of countries).

E.g,

```
from countryinfo import CountryInfo
s = CountryInfo('South Africa')
print(s.info()['subregion']) # displays 'Southern Africa'
```

While this library is useful, this library relies on only the country names. I would like an alternative method to achieve the intended output as above but using latitudes/longitudes.

I do know that an easy solution is just to fetch the country name from the latitudes/longitudes and then just pass that to countryinfo but is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

To get info (like `subregion`) from a country using `latlng` coordinates, we can search through `all()` countries until the `latlng` coordinates match; however, not all country info listed has `latlng` in its `dict` so we have to check if it `contains` that `item`:

```
!pip install countryinfo
import countryinfo
from countryinfo import CountryInfo
latlng = [-29, 24]
def get_subregion(latlng):
    for _, country_info in CountryInfo().all().items():
        if country_info.__contains__('latlng') and country_info.__getitem__('latlng') == latlng:
            return f"Coordinates {latlng} matched to {country_info.__getitem__('name')}, its subregion: {country_info.__getitem__('subregion')}"
    return f'Could not find a match for coordinates {latlng}'

get_subregion(latlng)
```

outputs:

```
Coordinates [-29, 24] matched to South Africa, its subregion: Southern Africa
```